# Oracle slow down unexpected and rapidly when using sql "update" continuously

Tags: oracle, qt, sql-update, slowdown

The situation is simple, there is a table in oracle used as a "shared table" for data exchange. The table structure and number of records remains unchanged. In normal case, I continuously update data into this table and other process read this table for current data.

Strange thing is, when my process starts, the time consumption of each update statement execution is approximately 2 ms. And after a certain peroid of time(like 8 hours), the time consumption increased to 10 ~ 20 ms per statement. It makes the procedure quite slow.

[the structure of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XNFj.png)

and the update statement is like:

```
anaNum = anaList.size(); 
qry.prepare(tr("update YC set MEAVAL=:MEAVAL, QUALITY=:QUALITY, LASTUPDATE=:LASTUPDATE where YCID=:YCID")); 
foreach(STbl_ANA ana, anaList) 
{ 
   qry.bindValue(":MEAVAL",ana.meaVal); 
   qry.bindValue(":QUALITY",ana.quality); 
   qry.bindValue(":LASTUPDATE",QDateTime::fromTime_t(ana.lastUpdate)); 
   qry.bindValue(":YCID",ana.ycId); 
   if(!qry.exec()) 
   { 
     qWarning() << QObject::tr("update yc failed, ") 
        << qry.lastError().databaseText() << qry.lastError().driverText(); 
     failedAnaList.append(ana); 
   } 
}
```

[the update statement using qt interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzkBw.png)

There is many reasons which can cause orcle opreation slowd down, but I cannot find a clue to explain this.

1. I never start a transaction manually in qt code, which means the commit operation is executed every time after update statement.
2. The update frequency is about 200 records per second, but the number is dynamically changed by time. It maybe increase to 1000 in one time and drop to 10 in next time.
3. once the time consumption up to 10 ~ 20 ms per statement, it'll never dorp down. **time consumption can be restored to 2ms only be restart oracle service**.(it's useless to shutdown or restart any user process which visit orcle)

Please tell me how to solve it or at least what to be examined.

Comment: Please type the information from the images into the body of the question, to save clicking through, enable copying and searching, etc.

Comment: anaNum = anaList.size();
   qry.prepare(tr("update YC set MEAVAL=:MEAVAL, QUALITY=:QUALITY, LASTUPDATE=:LASTUPDATE where YCID=:YCID"));
   foreach(STbl_ANA ana, anaList)
   {
    qry.bindValue(":MEAVAL",ana.meaVal);
    qry.bindValue(":QUALITY",ana.quality);
    qry.bindValue(":LASTUPDATE",QDateTime::fromTime_t(ana.lastUpdate));
    qry.bindValue(":YCID",ana.ycId);
    if(!qry.exec())
    {
     qWarning() << QObject::tr("update yc failed, ")
      << qry.lastError().databaseText() << qry.lastError().driverText();
     failedAnaList.append(ana);
    }
   }

Comment: @user6180123 : welcome to SO. "anaNum = ..." Do _not_ put that in a comment, instead _edit your question_ to add this info (using proper code formating of course).

Comment: I know, but the code is not the point.The point is, same sql every time, almost same frequency, but suddenly, the oracle performance drop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good starting points is to check the [AWR and ASH](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/doc.112/e12152/intro.htm#CHDGGJAF) reports.

Comparing the reports in "good" and "bad" times you can spot the cause of the change. This can be for example a *change of an execution plan or increase of wait events*. One possible outcome is that only change you see is that the *database is waiting more time on the client* (i.e. the problem is not in the DB).

Anyway as diagnosed in other answer, the root cause of problems seems to be the update in a loop. If your update lists are long (say more that 10-100 entries) you can profit by updating the whole list in a single statement using MERGE.

- build a collection from your list
- cast the collection as TABLE
- use this table in a MERGE statement to update the rows.

See [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:7510410512718) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can trace the session while it is running quickly and again later when it is running slowly. Use the sql trace functionality and tkprof to get a breakdown of where the update is spending its time in each case and see what has changed.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25178_01/server.1111/e16638/sqltrace.htm#i4640

If you need help interpreting the results you can update your question or ask a new one.

Secondly, as a rule single record updates are not the best way to do updates in Oracle. Since you have many records to update already prepared before you prepare the query, look at execBatch.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#execBatch

This will both execute the update faster and only issue a single commit.